# dealing with other programmers' complex arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am maintaining an OO PHP application that loads everything to $this array. When I do a var dump on $this to find out how to access a value, I get dozens of pages of output. Hunting down the array elements that I need is very time consuming

For example, if I want to find where Customer Territory is stored, I have to figure out the heirarchy of the array using print_r or var_dump and staring [**edit:** and searching] ]at the output until I figure out the path.

for example:
$this->Billing->Cst->Record['Territory']

Is there a better way to do this, or some tools/techniques that I can use.  For instance, is there there quick way to find the path to variable ['Territory'] throughout the array directly?

Comment: Rather than staring, have you considered using grep?

Comment: @Oli his issue is finding out the right "address" to access an element, rather than finding the element itself (which, as you say, is easy using grep).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) is a graphical "var_dump" tool that may make navigation a tiny bit easier. Check out the "examples" section on the project page.

For searching in multi-dimensional arrays, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097043/searching-in-a-multi-dimensional-array-php) may help you.

Comment: Thank you. I found the path. It looked like this.. krumo($this->Billing->Tables['Payment']->Tables['Customer']->Tables['Address']->Item['ProvinceStateId']);  I didn;t realize that you could mix objects and arrays like this.

Comment: @hank oh my goodness. You definitely need a tool for that kind of data! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do ctr+F on the output instead of staring at it?

Just start with ctr+F: "Customer", "Territory" and all other names related to whatever you're searching.

Answer (score 1):

```
function findInTree($var, $words) {
    $words = explode(' ', strtolower($words));
    $path = array();
    $depth = 0;
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($var), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
        if ($iterator->getDepth() < $depth) {
            unset($path[$depth]);
        }
        $depth = $iterator->getDepth();
        $path[$depth] = $key;

        if (is_string($key) && in_array(strtolower($key), $words)) {
            echo '<pre>', implode(' -&gt; ', $path), '</pre>';
        }
    }
}

findInTree($this, 'Customer Territory');
```

This function will walk through your object and look for any of the given words as a key.

Answer (score 0):

[`FirePHP/Firebug`](http://www.firephp.org) can give you a detailed structural view of `$this` and its properties.